# Rust how to define benchmark only dependencies in Cargo?

Tags: rust, build, benchmarking, rust-cargo

How can I only include a package used for benchmarking when I run `cargo bench`?

The documentation for targets suggests that this is possible but I can't get it to work.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html

Comment: Optional dev dependencies is a long requested feature, see https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1596.

Answer (score 3):

Benchmark dependencies don't get their own section in `cargo.toml`. You need to put them in the `[dev-dependencies]` along with test dependencies.

Comment: That's a shame but thank you.  I've kept them out of the released package at least.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Dogbert in the comments, there is a related issue:
https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1596

There is also this useful suggestion to move the benchmarks/quickcheck into a separate repository and use the public interface.

> @bluss bluss commented on 2 May 2020 For such cases like benchmarks,
> for now I'd recommend using an additional non-published crate that you
> keep in the same repository, that depends on your library and contains
> the benchmarks. It will need to use the public APIs, of course, but
> that's ok in most cases. As an example of this, ndarray has a
> subdirectory for blas-tests that runs tests that depend on BLAS.